# Alterar fundo com js

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Bom, tenho uma imagem para demonstração

http://prntscr.com/8xu33k

Quando um usuário clicar em uma, o fundo da body vai mudar de acordo com o que ele escolheu. Mas nesse caso o fundo é uma imagem que corresponde a essas cores. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base de como você quer adaptando o código do Leandro:

```
    $("#azul").click(function() {
    $("body").css({
    "background": "url(azul.png)";
    });

    $("#cinza").click(function() {
    $("body").css({
    "background": "url(cinza.png)";
    });

    $("#vermelho").click(function() {
    $("body").css({
    "background": "url(vermelho.png)";
    });
    });
```

Comment: vlw mano, queria isso mesmo, valeu leandro tbm

Answer (score 0):

Bom com javascript é mais dificil... Vou usar jquery se vc quiser usar usa !

```
<div id="azul">azul</div>
<br>
<div id="vermelho">vermelho</div>
<br>
<div id="cinza">cinza</div>
<br>
```

Bom só vc ler e codigo n é dificil... qualquer coisa falae

```
$("#azul").click(function() {
      $("body").css({
        "background": "blue";
     });

      $("#cinza").click(function() {
        $("body").css({
          "background": "#ccc";
        });

        $("#vermelho").click(function() {
          $("body").css({
            "background": "red";
          });
        });
```

EDIT: Leandro, não se esqueça de colocar ";" para fechar. Isso é importante.

Comment: Entendi. Eu pensava que isso era js kkk eu confundo os dois

Comment: Mas como faço para colocar em imagem?

Comment: simples  - em vez do #ccc ou a cor vc coloca o caminho da imagem tipo  "background": "url(img.png)" desculpa a demora pois eu to programando.